# two times second ArgumentCaptor.capture() inside Mockito.when()

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

The issue is I have two argumentCaptors, and i need to use `Mockito.when().then()` two times, with this `argumentCaptors.capture()` in paramenets of method inside `when()`. But It run two times second `argumentCaptor.capture()`

i know that in verify i can use `argumentCaptor.getAllValues().get(i)`, and get any of values of current argumentCaptors, but i can not find something about how to use the same thing for `capture()` method, inside `Mockito.when()`

```java
Set<String> ordersBuy = mock(Set.class);
Set<String> ordersSell = mock(Set.class);

ArgumentCaptor<Function<CurrencyPairDTO, String >> getBase = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Function.class);
ArgumentCaptor<Function<CurrencyPairDTO, String>> getCounter = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Function.class);
ArgumentCaptor<Function<MyOrdersSmartDTO, Set<String>>> getSell = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Function.class);
ArgumentCaptor<Function<MyOrdersSmartDTO, Set<String>>> getBuy = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Function.class);

when(this.recalculateInMemoryBoardUtils.fillSetByMarginOrdersUsingFunctions(eq(instancesByUsername), eq(currencyBase), getBase.capture(), getSell.capture())).thenReturn(ordersSell);
when(this.recalculateInMemoryBoardUtils.fillSetByMarginOrdersUsingFunctions(eq(instancesByUsername), eq(currencyBase), getCounter.capture(), getBuy.capture())).thenReturn(ordersBuy);
```

i received two times ordersBuy instead of ordersSell, ordersBuy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use here `thenAnswer()`, and check our parameters

`when(this.recalculateInMemoryBoardUtils.fillSetByMarginOrdersUsingFunctions(eq(instancesByUsername), eq(currencyBase), any(), any())).thenAnswer(`
                `(Answer<Set<String>>) invocationOnMock -> {
                    Function<CurrencyPairDTO, String> function = invocationOnMock.getArgument(2);
                    CurrencyPairDTO currencyPairFunction = CurrencyPairDTO.builder()
                            .base(currencyBase)
                            .counter(currencyCounter)
                            .build();
                    String currency = function.apply(currencyPairFunction);
                    if (currencyBase.equals(currency)) {
                        return ordersBuy;
                    } else {
                        return ordersSell;
                    }
                });`

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito.thenReturn()` supports [consecutive calls](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#10) by using a vararg. Therefore, you can combine them:

```java
ArgumentCaptor<Function<CurrencyPairDTO, String >> currencyPairCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Function.class);
ArgumentCaptor<Function<MyOrdersSmartDTO, Set<String>>> myOrderSmartCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Function.class);

when(recalculateInMemoryBoardUtils.fillSetByMarginOrdersUsingFunctions(eq(instancesByUsername), eq(currencyBase), currencyPairCaptor.capture(), myOrderSmartCaptor.capture())).thenReturn(ordersSell, ordersBuy);
```

And then use `getAllValues().get(0)` and `getAllValues().get(1)` like you suggested.

Furthermore, it might be better to return an empty `Set` instead of mocking it, as mocking it makes the process more difficult later on. For instance, if you method under test invokes `someSet.contains(someVal)`, you'll have to mock a basic `Set` operation in order for the test to function.

Comment: TY, but its a bit not that i want. I've got an answer now